# Insert special characters to database in Zend

Tags: zend-framework, utf-8

I Try to add following form array to data base in the Zend freamwork Db_abstract function ($db->insert($data))

```
$data = array(
    [name] => Dinuka
    [special_request] => I'm Dinuka Ö é Ñ Thilanga 
)
```

But special_request values did not insert correctly. It insert only 'I'm Dinuka'. Other values are drop when insert the query.

I set following prams in my application.ini

```
resources.db.adapter = PDO_MYSQL
resources.db.params.host = 192.168.0.xxx
resources.db.params.username = xxxxx
resources.db.params.password = xxxxx
resources.db.params.dbname = xxxxx
resources.db.params.charset = utf8
```

Please help me. How I insert special values into the database as correct way.

Comment: Can you run a [SHOW CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-table.html) and add the table SQL to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Are you try to insert this utf-8 query from Command Line?

Maybe The problem is with postgres DB and not related to Zend adapter...

Comment: I can insert those data using phpmyadmin. my database is mysql.

Answer (score 0):

set the field's Collation as utf8_general_ci and try inserting again.